# Check "CONNECTION LIMIT" of user in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a user in Redshift with username as **"redshift_x"** and want to know the CONNECTION LIMIT which is currently set for this user. I have tried querying it using the below query:

> select * from pg_user where usename = 'redshift_x';

But this query only gives information about these columns viz. usename, usesysid, usecreatedb, usesuper, usecatupd, passwd, valuntil, useconfig.

Kindly let me know from where can I see the CONNECTION LIMIT for this particular user **"redshift_x"**.

Comment: I haven't manually set the limit to a user using `ALTER USER` query. However, can you check once whether the WLM has the entry recorded in AWS console? Since the WLM also deals with concurrency limits, I am searching through these documentations to see if anything is available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were very close with the view, there is one more that has the info you need. 
`select * from pg_user_info` (a view in the pg_catalog).

The column you are after is useconnlimit